# marathon sticky seesion how to enable for apllication level session management

Tags: session-cookies, marathon, internal-load-balancer

Can someone help how to configure marathon lb to enable session on my single packaged web application. I dont have any service. Its just an web application having session management.

I do not want to implement different caching layer to maintain session but want to enable session with some configuration change.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please review; [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In the marathon-lb documentation, you can find additional information about how to enable sticky sessions within marathon-lb:

```
marathon_lb.py has a lot of additional functionality like sticky sessions, HTTP to HTTPS redirection, SSL offloading, virtual host support and templating capabilities.

To get the full documentation run:

$ ./marathon_lb.py --help
```

https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb